# How do I make an inner edge loop parallel to an outer edge loop?

Tags: modeling

For this object I need an inner contour parallel to the outer contour. If I use *Extrude* (<kbd>E</kbd>) and *Scale* (<kbd>S</kbd>), and reduce the outer contour, an inner contour is created. However, this does not run parallel to the outer contour. Instead of moving inward, the contour is moving to the outside.

Is there a command that creates a uniform inner contour? In the above example I tried the desired one by hand, that is a) inaccurate and b) very time consuming.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use Shrink/fatten <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> with Offset Even option instead:

[image]

And don't forget apply scale in object mode! (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Scale)

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do this.

You could use Solidify function:

[image]

Solidify Modifier would work similarly, just from the Object mode:

[image]

You could extrude the faces(<kbd>e</kbd>) and confirm extrude by clicking without moving the mouse for the faces to stay on top of the old ones and then Shrink/Flatten with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as well. If you pres <kbd>s</kbd> while the operation is in progress it will make the offset even. This makes t easier to deal with overlaping beveled corners as you can stop, remove doubles (<kbd>w</kbd>><kbd>r</kbd>) and then carry on with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> :

[image]